# Python SMTP Email Message Body Showing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, smtp

I have been trying to make the content or message body to appear in the emails but it doesn't appear to be working.  It's mentioned that a empty line is needed before the message and with new line after subject.  Also, each time I run the script it runs but gives this error "Task timed out after 3.01 seconds" but I get the email, however, the Lambda function is marked as Failed...not sure why?? Maybe that's not so much of a big deal but if it ran then I'm assuming it was successful which is confusing since it says failed. The biggest thing here is the content not showing up.  Thank you for any assistance.

```
import smtplib
            
sender = 'example.org'
recipient = contact


        try:
            subject = str(instance_name) + ' Issues'
            content="Hello World" 
            mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()
            mail.login('example.org','1234567890')
            header = 'To:' + recipient + '\n' + 'From:' \
            +sender+'\n'+'subject:' + subject  + '\n'
            content=header+content
            mail.sendmail(sender, recipient, content)
         

        except:
            print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the timeout? Is your AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, why did you choose to connect it to a VPC?

Comment: I've been looking for the correct syntax for increasing the timeout but it's not clear but I'm assuming it's "mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587, 600)" the number after the port?  It's not corrected to a VPC.

Comment: I changed this line of code "+sender+'\n'+'subject:' + subject  + '\n\n' " and it appears to be working, it will give me email a simple "hello world" but when I try and email the email body as a string str(email), the body does not show up, what gives?  a string is a string, right?

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line of code `"+sender+'\n'+'subject:' + subject + '\n\n' "` and it appears to be working.  As far as the timeout issue.  I increased it to a minute and it works fine now.